# Auto-create the containing module of a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails you can create a model under `app/foo/bar.rb`, with bar.rb containing:

```
class Foo::Bar
  def some_method
    puts "I work fine"
  end
end
```

If you try to do this in a pure ruby app you'd get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo` unless you've already initialized a module `Foo`.

What is Rails doing that allows it to create classes without first initializing their containing module? Is it possible to import this behavior through something like activesupport, or are we left to implement on our own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails modifies the `Class` class to include a [`const_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_missing) method which gets called when an undefined class is used.  It then loads things to try and load the requested class.

The implementation of this in ActiveSupport is in `lib/active_support/dependencies.rb`.

Comment: Here is what I did to implement:
In your gem file: `gem 'activesupport', :require => 'active_support/dependencies'`
Then in your code, just add your folders:

`['app/models', 'app/controllers', 'app/helpers'].each { |f| ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << File.expand_path(f) }`

Answer (score -1):

actually model class created is extend to < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: You don't have to create models extending ActiveRecord, you can create models extending anything (or nothing). The Rails behavior of auto-creating a module is not specific to models extending ActiveRecord.